# ¿Como quito de una web un iframe con una página que rechaza la conexión y no me permite editar?

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo una web en Jimdo para ayudar a estudiantes de una facultad y que puedan recibirse. Quise incluir un iframe de prueba con un módulo para html. El código estaba de ejemplo en este mismo sitio y lo dirige a aquí, sucede que me quita toda posibilidad de  editar para quitar el módulo con el código del iframe, y queda inutilizada. Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.
Código:

```html
<body>
<iframe src="http://es.stackoverflow.com" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;">
</iframe>
</body>
```

La página es [1]
[1]: https://actualizacionesfolp.jimdofree.com/

La imagen es
[image: (lo que se visualiza es aún en modo edición.]

Comment: Que pasa si quitas el iframe??

Comment: Ese es el problema que tengo, esta página, "stackoverflow", me redirecciona a este sitio y  bloquea la conexión, por lo tanto no me permite modificar nada. Que me redirecciona lo descubrí descargando la página de jimdo a mi Pc, (para poder copiar contenido) con Cyotek WebCopy, cuando le doy al archivo "index.htm". Aclaro que no edito mediante plantilla, sino mediante módulos de jimdo.

Comment: La verdad desconozco de Jimdo pero te puedo asegurar algo. Si entras en tu hosting puedes modificar lo que sea o reemplazar lo que tu quieras, por lo demás según el código que pones en la pregunta colocaste un iframe que lo más probable era de prueba, porque de que otra forma querrías un iframe a SOes?? Así como subiste tu primer pagina la puedes reemplazar quitando lo que te esta generando el error. PD: Jimdo es una plataforma para crear páginas web y tiendas en línea​ que **cuenta con un propio sistema de gestión de contenido que funciona como un editor WYSIWYG.**